# How to use style.width if value is string?

Tags: angular

I have width that i get like string. `For example : "150"`.When i do like this :

`class="{{event.width}}"` i get in class value but if i do like this : `style.width="width + 'px"` i dont get anything. Any suggestion ? Is it problem because im getting it like string and it expect a number or ? Because in class i get a value so value exists. I also tried `[ngStyle]={'width':event.width'}` but same problem nothing happend. I dont get value inside html.

Comment: did you use [style.width] for the style binding?

Comment: yes ... i want to add width to style in html

Comment: try one of these, `[style.width]="width + 'px'"` or `[ngStyle]="{'width': event.width}"`

Comment: i already try that ... i wrote in my post that

Comment: you didn't specify third brackets around the `style.width` in your question, thats why I asked

Comment: i used brackets but not working im not sure is that because i get width as string

Comment: @uzhas angular doesnt mind that `event.width` is a string.

Answer (score 2):

The following examples show both ways of style binding in Angular. Suppose you have a width field that is string type,

```
public width = "400";
```

Following techniques will set the width of the button controls to `400px`,

```
<button [ngStyle]="{'width.px': width }">Button 1</button>

<button [style.width]="width + 'px'">Button 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `ngStyle`

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'width.px': event.width}">...</div>
```

Here is a working [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/uK5r1ZizjCGod9PD67wN?p=preview) to demo this.

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing with

```
<div [style.width]="event.width + 'px'">...</div>
```

or

```
<div [ngStyle]="{width: event.width + 'px'}">...</div>
```

however I believe the first option is the most elegant